# Cybersource payment gateway failing transactions for less than 2000$

Tags: payment-gateway, cybersource

I am using Cybersource payment gateway for one of my projects.

In sandbox mode, When I do payments for less than 2000$, an error is coming like this:

```
{
  "utf8": "✓",
  "req_card_number": "xxxxxxxxxxxx0004",
  "req_locale": "en",
  "signature": "CsAocZRprW4m/SZQmaFLLiG7FQ55LVOrd5oQ342Ikr0=",
  "req_card_type_selection_indicator": "1",
  "req_bill_to_surname": "test",
  "req_bill_to_address_city": "test",
  "req_card_expiry_date": "02-2020",
  "req_bill_to_address_postal_code": "12231",
  "reason_code": "203",
  "auth_response": "303",
  "req_bill_to_forename": "test",
  "req_payment_method": "card",
  "request_token": "Ahj77wSTIH0d5owGkfErEUuPy7nKACS4/LucoNII9TAgCky9JMvRiundKAOkyB9HeaMBpHxKwAAA9APe",
  "req_amount": "1200",
  "req_bill_to_email": "test@trext.com",
  "transaction_id": "5321677908746496504107",
  "req_currency": "USD",
  "req_card_type": "002",
  "decision": "DECLINE",
  "message": "We encountered a Paymentech problem: Reason: Processor Decline.",
  "signed_field_names": "transaction_id,decision,req_access_key,req_profile_id,req_transaction_uuid,req_transaction_type,req_reference_number,req_amount,req_currency,req_locale,req_payment_method,req_bill_to_forename,req_bill_to_surname,req_bill_to_email,req_bill_to_address_line1,req_bill_to_address_line2,req_bill_to_address_city,req_bill_to_address_country,req_bill_to_address_postal_code,req_card_number,req_card_type,req_card_type_selection_indicator,req_card_expiry_date,message,reason_code,auth_avs_code,auth_response,request_token,signed_field_names,signed_date_time",
  "req_transaction_uuid": "5b53064a835dd",
  "auth_avs_code": "1",
  "req_bill_to_address_country": "TW",
  "req_transaction_type": "authorization",
  "req_access_key": "b187124a88c434fd83d5c231073d3cff",
  "req_profile_id": "5AFB52E0-B68E-477C-9605-C400061D07E0",
  "req_reference_number": "35",
  "req_bill_to_address_line2": "test",
  "signed_date_time": "2018-07-21T10:09:50Z",
  "req_bill_to_address_line1": "test"
}
```

For more than $2000, it working fine.
Can anybody tell me why it is like that?? is it a feature of the sandbox mode.

Answer (score 1):

In CAS requests don't hit payment processors, they hit simulators. Specific amounts, along with other fields are used to trigger particular responses for testing purposes. See: https://www.cybersource.com/developers/getting_started/test_and_manage/simple_order_api/

Answer (score 0):

You need to talk to the merchant account provider, Paymentech, as they are the ones who are declining the transactions so stated in the error message. This is not a coding issue.